# Why some of the public SageMaker ECR images give ecr:BatchGetImage permission errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I have tried some of the Docker registries for Sagemaker (for region [eu-north-1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ecr-eu-north-1.html) and region [us-east-1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ecr-us-east-1.html))  and I can pull from some of those registries not from other. I  don't understand why.

As far as I know all those ECR registries are "public" and the IAM policy for my user allows everything.

But I'm getting the following error on some of those "public" registries:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/ecerulm-iam is not authorized to perform: ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:eu-north-1:669576153137:repository/blazingtext because no resource-based policy allows the ecr:BatchGetImage action
```

Here is some examples:

```
# image_uris.retrieve(framework='sklearn',region='eu-north-1',version='0.23-1',image_scope='inference') -> '662702820516.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py3'
docker pull 662702820516.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py3 # works

# image_uris.retrieve(framework='blazingtext',region='eu-north-1')
 -> '669576153137.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/blazingtext:1'
docker pull '669576153137.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/blazingtext:1'
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 669576153137.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/blazingtext, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/ecerulm-iam is not authorized to perform: ecr:BatchGetImage on resource: arn:aws:ecr:eu-north-1:669576153137:repository/blazingtext because no resource-based policy allows the ecr:BatchGetImage action
```

This same error when I try to pull these images (obtained with `sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve()`

- 669576153137.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/blazingtext:1
- 763603941244.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-clarify-processing:1.0
- 811284229777.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blazingtext:1
- 205585389593.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-clarify-processing:1.0
- 382416733822.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/factorization-machines:1
- 382416733822.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ipinsights:1

but for these it works OK:

- 662702820516.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py3
- 683313688378.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py3
- 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/autogluon-inference:0.4-cpu-py38
- 520713654638.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-chainer:5.0.0-cpu-py3
- 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-tensorflow-training:2.6.3-transformers4.17.0-gpu-py38-cu112-ubuntu20.04

What is causing this? What is the difference between those docker images? Aren't those "public" as I though they were? I just wanted to run the images locally to debug / troubleshoot.